# Why does Google keep saying "Invalid URL"?

Tags: firefox, osx-lion, internet-connection

About once a week I try to visit the site "www.google.com" but a page appears that says:

> **Invalid URL**
>
> The requested URL "/", is invalid.
>
> Reference #9.ac9a1645.1315262080.114e51c8"

I'm using Firefox 6 on Mac OS X Lion.

[image]

Any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This isn't Google. Nor is it Facebook, the IMDB, Apple or any of the other WWW sites that people post "NNN is down!" complaints about all over the WWW, listing this error.

This error comes from Akamai, and it's the error when an Akamai server wants to serve up an HTTP 400 response.  Although the error is generated when an HTTP request to an Akamai server lacks a `Host:` header, it's unlikely that such a thing just starts happening in a WWW browser, happens only intermittently, and happens for specific domain names.

The more likely cause is that Akamai has messed things up.

Comment: Somebody is being a bit harsh.

Comment: I've removed the ranty bit in the beginning.

Comment: You didn't remove a "ranty bit".  You removed information useful to anyone who has put the error message into a WWW search engine to try to find out what it means, and found umpteen different companies and organizations being blamed for this error.  We're trying to help such people here, M. West.  Deleting information from one of the few places on the WWW where the actual culprit is identified, and the fact that this behaviour is errroneosuly ascribed to a wide range of entites observed, isn't helping people.  It's reducing SuperUser to being as bad and uninformative as all of the rest.